# Can I change the access of my variables in a Typescript class?

Tags: typescript, class, variables

When I have a class in Typescript with two variables, one is public and the other one is private. That means that no one could access to the private variable but how would the class have to be added to allow the access? I don't want to just change it to public, I want to *add* something to the class/code, so someone could have access to the private attribute from outside the class.

Comment: *I hope you understand my question*: no, to be fait, I don't. If you want a property to be accessible from outside the class, it must be public. If you don't want that, it should be private. Why wouldn't you "just change it to public" if you want  it to be publicly accessible? What concrete problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a getter?

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve] as described by [ask], so someone could make a concrete suggestion.  Are you talking about a [`private` property](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-private-and-protected-modifiers)?  Or a [private class field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Private_fields_Experimental)?

Comment: As far as I'm aware the closest thing to that is being able to "subtract" readonly from properties: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#readonly-mapped-type-modifiers-and-readonly-arrays `type Writable<T> = { -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] }`. You can't do the same thing with `private` or `protected`.